# Script assigns a null value to a variable

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, if-statement, com

I wrote a script to check the result of submitting a string to a web page.
I then check if the resulting string contains a certain substring and the script *should* act accordingly with an if loop.
For some reason, the variable that's suppose to contain the string is equal to `$null`.
The weird part is - this ONLY happens when I run the script as a script, but not when I run the specific command line in the ISE.

The relevant part of the code is:

```
$Result = $($objIE.Document.getElementById("JSONResultDiv")).innertext
if ($Result -like "*true*")
{
    Write-Host "True" 
}
else
{
    Write-Host "False"
}
```

I tried using `Set-PSDebug -Trace 2` and it showed me the statement comes out true, yet the script still executed the false clause(?!)
Moreover, if I put `Write-Host $result` after defining the variable it works. Same with a breakpoint. If I set a breakpoint just after checking the statement and before entering the if loop itself, it shows that it defined the variable.
I feel confused, what am I missing?

Comment: so is the `$Result` `$null`?

Comment: Yeah, the result variable is null, not even an empty string.

Comment: Well, what does `$($objIE.Document.getElementById("JSONResultDiv")).innertext` this return, if you debug it and grab the value right after it gets assigned?

Comment: Well, it gives me the right string (the string is in hebrew, I'm not really looking for "true" in the string, but an hebrew word), it contains the word I want the when I invoke $Result -like "*wordhere*" it outputs "True"

Comment: then you should do your validation like if it `if($result.length -gt 0){Write-Host "True" }else{"False"}`

Comment: @RanadipDutta that could lead to false positives, obviously. Can you test that in the script, so just `$var = 'hebrewword'; $var -like '*hebreweord*'`

Comment: `$var = 'hebrewword'; $var -like '*hebrewword*'`-- I tried this. Resulting me true.

Comment: second part was to the op

Comment: O..You have to use **$true**.. NOw I figured it out that you are writing *true* which is not the same as $true.. try this `$var = 'hebrewword'; 
$var=$var -like '*hebrewword*'


if ($var -like $true)
{
    Write-Host "True" 
}
else
{
    Write-Host "False"
}`

Comment: It comes out true, funny thing is I moved it a few rows downwards and now it works... Well, if it ain't broke... I ain't gonna fix it. Thank you guys!

Comment: @OrelFichman: accept the comment(s) if it helps you.

Comment: @RanadipDutta Comments cannot be accepted, only upvoted (which doesn't do anything but indicate how many users agreed with the comment). The correct thing to do (provided you have enough reputation to do so) would be voting to close the question because the problem cannot be reproduced anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind.